# ng-repeat with filter yields unwanted $index

Tags: html, angularjs

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ernestsoo22/qqgj9jf5/1/

I have a `ng-repeat` in my code like this:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat=" opt in courses">
    {{$index}}
</li>
</ul>
```

With this, I am able to get the output of:

> 0 , 1 , 2 , 3

**Problem:** Using a filter like such does not get the `$index` that I want:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat=" opt in courses | filter:{code:'INF'}"   >
    {{$index}}
</li>
</ul>
```

With this filter I get the `$index` of (refer fiddle):

> 0 , 1

Instead of this, what I am looking for is to get the actual index of the `courses` json object. So according to the filter, the output would be:

> 2 , 3

How can I achieve this while using a `filter`?

Comment: doh! What if you just use an ng-if bro?

Comment: If you can add ID/Index property in your course Object then you can directly display index as you desire. {{opt.Index}}
$index will return indexes of the resultant array with the filter applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-if="opt.code.indexOf('INF')>=0"` in `li` to check the filter to check the `INF` present

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.courses = [
    {"code":"ICT10001","description":"Problem Solving with ICT","credits":"12.5","type":"Core"},
    {"code":"COS10005","description":"Web Development","credits":"12.5","type":"Core"},
    {"code":"INF10003","description":"Introduction to Business Information Systems","credits":"12.5","type":"Core"},
    {"code":"INF10002","description":"Database Analysis and Design","credits":"12.5","type":"Core"}];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat=" opt in courses" ng-if="opt.code.indexOf('INF')>=0"   >
    {{$index}}
    </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li ng-repeat=" opt in courses">
    <span ng-if="opt.code==='INF'">{{$index}}</span>
</li>
```

Does that fix it?